# Which branches of mathematics can be done just in terms of morphisms and composition?

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, soft-question, foundations

Consider the first-order language $L_{\omega\omega}$ of the signature $L:=\{\mathrm{dom}, \mathrm{cod}, \mathrm{comp}\}$, where $\mathrm{dom}$ and $\mathrm{cod}$ are unary function symbols and $\mathrm{comp}$ is a ternary relation symbol. This is intended to be thought of as the language of a single category: $\mathrm{dom}$ resp. $\mathrm{cod}$ are interpreted as functions yielding the *domain* resp. *codomain* of a given morphism; $\mathrm{comp}(h, g, f)$ is interpreted as $h=g\circ f$. One can formally write down the axioms of a category (associativity of composition, identity morphisms for composition) as first-order $L$-sentences. If we call the collection of these axioms $T_\text{Cat}$, then an $L$-structure $C$ with $C\models T_\text{Cat}$ is essentially the same as a category. (Okay, one can argue about size issues or whether specific decisions concerning the design of the formal language are natural, for example, whether it would be better to use a two-sorted language with the sorts "objects" and "morphisms" rather than a one-sorted language where everything is a morphism, but let us ignore these issues for now.)

Lawvere famously gave an axiomatization $\mathsf{ETCS}\supseteq T_{\mathrm{Cat}}$ of the category of sets in the language $L_{\omega\omega}$ and showed that a great deal of set theory can be carried out in this theory. I think it is quite remarkable that all the usual concepts of set theory (such as elements, the set of natural numbers, and the cartesian product) can be formulated categorically in the language $L_{\omega\omega}$ of morphisms. Here are some links for further reading for people not familiar with $\mathsf{ETCS}$: [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS), [Lawvere's original paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC300477/pdf/pnas00186-0196.pdf), [fully formal presentation of ETCS on the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fully+formal+ETCS), [Tom Leinster's "Rethinking set theory"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6543.pdf). Lawvere also gave an axiomatization $\mathsf{ETCC}$ of the category of categories ([nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCC)). (To me, this theory seems to be not as established as $\mathsf{ETCS}$ and I don't know to what extent this theory can be used to carry out doing category theory.)

**Question:** Is it also possible to axiomatize the category of topological spaces (and continuous maps) in the language $L_{\omega\omega}$? Is it then possible to really carry out some topology in this theory? Also, is it possible to axiomatize the category of groups resp. rings in $L_{\omega\omega}$ and then really do some group resp. ring theory? (You can really interpret my question as a question schema: for each theory, you can ask this question.) This would be interesting, because it would show that one can do topology, group theory, ring theory, ... *without presupposing some form of set theory*. Also, it would show that one can express all (or a great deal of) the theorems of topology, group theory, ring theory, ... *just in terms of morphisms, domain, codomain, and composition*.

Comment: The question you've asked isn't really what you meant to, I think. ETCS **doesn't** axiomatize the category of sets fully - there are lots of statements about the category of sets, in the language above, which are independent of ETCS. This is relevant because when you ask "is it possible to axiomatize ---?," it's not clear what you mean by "axiomatize" - if you just mean "write some true statements about," then that's trivially true ($\emptyset$), while if you mean "give a complete axiomatization of" then that's false even for the category of sets. (cont'd)

Comment: Or at least, $(i)$ ETCS doesn't constitute such an axiomatization and $(ii)$ there is no *computable* axiomatization at all (the category of sets is complicated enough for Godel's incompleteness theorem to apply to its theory). As to "it would show that one can express all (or a great deal of) the theorems of topology, group theory, ring theory, ... just in terms of morphisms, domain, codomain, and composition," this is already well-known and one of the whole points of category theory in the first place. (cont'd)

Comment: I don't mean "axiomatizable" in the rigorous mathematical sense. I just wonder whether the theory (for example, topology) is axiomatizable *in such a way that a great deal of the theory can be done in the axiomatization*. Note that my question is a soft question. Basically, I just wonder: if one studies ETCS, why don't consider similar theories for topology, group theory, ring theory, ...

Comment: As to groups and rings they can be developed as 1 order theories, without sets (but these theories will not be equivalent to the usual group and ring theories, since everything connected to morphisms will be out of description). And your language seems to be too poor for describing what people are interested in these theories.

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov "your language seems to be too poor for describing what people are interested in these theories" I disagree with this - again, one of the whole points of category theory is that the language *is* rich enough to talk about a huge amount of the stuff we care about.

Comment: @user7280899 "if one studies ETCS, why don't consider similar theories for topology, group theory, ring theory, ..." This is for historical reasons. The interest in ETCS grew out of whether category theory could provide a foundation for mathematics independently (or mostly so) of set theory. One way to do this of course would be to axiomatize the category of sets "well enough." But this motivation is fairly limited. That said, there *is* plenty of interest in identifying key properties of categories, e.g. pinning down the notion of "abelian category," and this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Ultimately though, I suspect this question would be more appropriate for math.stackexchange (although not being a category theorist, I'm not sure).

Comment: @Noah: I agree that the point of category theory is to be a unifying language that is expressive enough to state many facts occuring in many fields of mathematics, but giving an axiomatization of a particular field just in terms of morphisms and composition and building up the theory just with these axioms is in my opinion a bit different. Category theory was developed in the 40s, and I think there was a reason why Lawvere developed a set theory just in the language of category theory, although one already knew that many facts can be expressed just in terms of morphisms and composition.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: "(i) ETCS doesn't constitute such an axiomatization and (ii) there is no computable axiomatization at all (the category of sets is complicated enough for Godel's incompleteness theorem to apply to its theory)" -- did you read the Lawvere paper a linked to, specifically his metatheorem and the corollary near the end?

Comment: @user7280899 Yes - completeness is *not* a first-order property, so that doesn't contradict what I wrote. (Here's an easy way to see why my claim is true: at least assuming ZFC, note that the finite sets are characterized in the category of sets as those satisfying "every arrow from me to me has an inverse," and categorial products and coproducts (modulo isos) provide the usual arithmetic structure on the definable subcategory of finite sets. So true arithmetic computably reduces to the theory of the category of sets - and indeed PA is interpretable in ETCS, so ETCS is essentially incomplete.)

Comment: Now it is interesting that ETCS pins down the category of sets (up to categorial equivalence) amongst the (locally small) complete categories - but that's a separate point. Also, note that **categorial equivalence doesn't imply elementary equivalence** - a category with 1 object can be categorially equivalent, but can never be elementarily equivalent, to a category with 2 objects (see the first example [on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_categories#Examples)). So *another* issue with applying Lawvere's metatheorem here is that it doesn't give elementary equivalence.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: You were criticizing my informal use of "axiomatization". I was just trying to say that if you want to make it more precise, you can consider the notion of axiomatization suggested by the meta theorem. I have the feeling you are doing a bit too much hairsplitting here. My question is just a soft-question about foundations, not a precise mathematical question.

Comment: Your question "did you read the Lawvere paper a linked to, specifically his metatheorem and the corollary near the end?" seemed to indicate that you disagreed with my statement about incompleteness (which you quoted in said comment), so I justified it; my apologies if I misunderstood your comment. As to softness, I recognize that this is a soft question - I think at present it is *too* soft, and could benefit from a further pinning-down of the relevant issues. I think there can be a good question here, but that more work is needed to tease it out.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Thank you for your comment. I was not disagreeing with your statement, I was just indicating that I used the word "axiomatization" not in the precise sense you were using it, and I referred to the metatheorem of Lawvere, because the metatheorem suggests a notion of "axiomatization" in which it would be true that ETCS is an axiomatization of the category of sets. Currently, I don't think that my question is too soft. I think that research questions don't have to be precise mathematical questions. (But, okay, maybe I'll edit my question in the future when I have an [continued]

Comment: idea to make it more clear.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90523/discussion-on-question-by-user7280899-which-branches-of-mathematics-can-be-done).

Comment: @ToddTrimble The comments themselves seem to have stuck around - is there an issue with the move-to-chat function (I thought it was supposed to merge, not duplicate)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber From my end, I have to manually delete comments under the post -- actually I could have also deleted their appearance under the post automatically, but wasn't sure what was desired -- for example, maybe keep the first few but remove the rest. Thoughts?

Comment: @ToddTrimble Oh I have no objection to any course of action, I was just surprised to see things stick around (and per my own issues with the function - when I tried to move to chat, it didn't work - I thought I'd mention it as a potential bug).

Comment: In my experience, both parties have to manually move themselves over to the newly-created chat room. Nothing seems to stop additional comments under the question (which is a good thing, in case new, pertinent points need to be made).

Comment: @NoahSchweber, re: [the finite sets are characterized in the category of sets as those satisfying "every arrow from me to me has an inverse"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324547/which-branches-of-mathematics-can-be-done-just-in-terms-of-morphisms-and-composi#comment810125_324547), surely you meant to put 'monic' or 'epic' or some other modifiers on the allowable arrows?

Comment: @LSpice Yes, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't really know what you're after but here is an analogue of ETCS for topological spaces

> Dana I. Schlomiuk, *An elementary theory of the category of topological spaces*, Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 149 (1970), 259-278, doi:[10.1090/S0002-9947-1970-0258914-7](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1970-0258914-7)

and here's one for (five different) categories of graphs

> Demitri Plessas, *The Categories of Graphs*, PhD thesis, University of Montana (2011) ([link](https://scholarworks.umt.edu/etd/967))

Comment: Thank you very much! In these papers, they do exactly what I was looking for! I suppose one can do the same with the category of groups, rings, ...